# how to write a loop to count elements in all column of a dataframe in r

Tags: r, loops, count, iteration

How can I write a loop that counts all elements in all columns of a dataframe in r and shows the result?

This is what I tried but I fail to show the result:

`count_1 <- for (col in colnames(df)){x = count(df, col)}`

Comment: maybe you can use nrow? I don't know what you want to count but a loop is probably not the best solution

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make a loop then, where `i` is each column and `j` is each element of the column, do

```
k <- 0
for(i in iris){
  for(j in i){
    k <- k+1
  }
}
k
```

But better to use `nrow(df) * ncol(df)` or `length(df$x) * length(df)` or something similar

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each cell in the data frame only contains one element, and not a list or vector itself, you could just multiply the dimensions. For example:

```r
set.seed(23L)
A <- data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = sample(LETTERS, 10), C = runif(10, 1, 3))
A
prod(dim(A))
```

This results in:

```r
             A B        C
1   0.19321233 V 1.698088
2  -0.43468211 M 1.658262
3   0.91326710 J 2.619008
4   1.79338809 L 1.548964
5   0.99660511 X 2.878190
6   1.10749049 F 2.804534
7  -0.27808628 G 1.354106
8   1.01920549 B 2.596503
9   0.04543718 O 1.165596
10  1.57577959 N 1.571384

[1] 30
```

If you have vectors within cells of the data frame, it gets a bit more complicated. We cant use `vapply` or `sapply` using `length` as that would only give the length of the table itself, not the length inside each cell. However, `rapply` is your friend here. If we call rapply on a list, and a data frame is a special kind of list, we will get the sums in each cell, so `sum(rapply(A, length))` should do what you want. Here is an example:

```r
A <- data.frame(A=double(2), B=double(2), C=character(2))
A$A <- list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4))
A$B <- list(7:9, 8:10)
A$C <- list(c('A', 'B'), c('D', 'E'))
A
     A        B    C
1 1, 2  7, 8, 9 A, B
2 3, 4 8, 9, 10 D, E

dim(A)
[1] 2 3

vapply(A, length, integer(1L))
A B C 
2 2 2 

rapply(A, length)
A1 A2 B1 B2 C1 C2 
 2  2  3  3  2  2 

sum(rapply(A, length))
[1] 14
```

And 14 is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use the data `iris`. You can use a loop like this to create a list and then create a table for each column in the data frame:

```
freq <- vector("list", length(iris))

for (i in seq_along(iris)){
    freq[[i]] <- table(iris[[i]])
}

str(freq)
List of 5
 $ : 'table' int [1:35(1d)] 1 3 1 4 2 5 6 10 9 4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr [1:35] "4.3" "4.4" "4.5" "4.6" ...
 $ : 'table' int [1:23(1d)] 1 3 4 3 8 5 9 14 10 26 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr [1:23] "2" "2.2" "2.3" "2.4" ...
 $ : 'table' int [1:43(1d)] 1 1 2 7 13 13 7 4 2 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr [1:43] "1" "1.1" "1.2" "1.3" ...
 $ : 'table' int [1:22(1d)] 5 29 7 7 1 1 7 3 5 13 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr [1:22] "0.1" "0.2" "0.3" "0.4" ...
 $ : 'table' int [1:3(1d)] 50 50 50
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
```

But perhaps using functionals is a better option:

```
lapply(iris, table)

apply(iris, 2, table)

sapply(iris, table)
```